# New MS CRM contact already has an Active Directory account. How do I pull from AD?

Tags: active-directory, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-3

I have some clients that I'd like to put into Microsoft CRM (3.0 Dynamics).  These people are already in a small Active Directory group for access to a couple of internal applications.

Is there a way to add these people to CRM and pull/push the contact data from Active Directory, so I'm not creating a second repository of information that conflict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no out-of-the-box way to dot his.  You'd have to write a custom app in order to query AD and pull in the data.  Unless you're looking at over 100 customers you probably won't make up the time it would take you to manually input this data.